# Confused with Vuex commit/dispatch in simple VueJS test

Tags: vue.js, vuex

From the book:

> To invoke a **[mutation handler](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html)**, you need to call **store.commit** with its type: `store.commit('increment')`

Mutations must always be synchronous.

---

From the book:

Actions commit mutations ( can be asynchronous )

> [Actions are triggered](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html) with the **store.dispatch** method: `store.dispatch('increment')`

So it's `action` -> `mutation` -> `new state` most of the time.

So what's confusing me, is the very simple example, whereby I'm trying to show the asynchronous result of an object `getTest`

**[See this pen](https://codepen.io/sidouglas/pen/ZJpXmv?editors=1011)**

Why can't Vue see that I'm *not calling a mutation*, but an *action* when the component loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is this "book" you are talking about? I'm asking because you are using a mix of new Vuex `2.*` and old, Vuex `1.*` syntax, which is not working anymore in `2.*`, so I assume you are learning in part from outdated resources.

*(Sidenote: Why are you using Vue 1? Vue`2.*` has been out for over 10 months now...)*

- Your action and mutation definitions are correct, but there's no `vuex: {}` key in components anymore in Vuex `2.*`
- Also, you are trying to dispatch an action 'INCREMENT', but oyour store only has a mutation by that name, no action. So you have to use `commit` rather than `dispatch`.

Instead, you directly add computed props and method to your instance, or use the `map*`helpers provided by Vuex:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '[vue=app]',
  data: {
    welcome: 'Testing Vuex'
  },
  store: myStore,
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch(FETCH_TEST_STATE)
  },
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapState( {
      count: state => state.count,
      getTest: state => state.testState
    }),
  }
  methods: {
   increment({dispatch}) {
     this.$store.commit('INCREMENT', 1)
   }
  }
})
```

- the action you call from `created` doesn't work because async/await was acting up on codepen
- the commit called from this action didn't set any state.

Fixing all of this, here's your working example:

https://codepen.io/LinusBorg/pen/NvRYYy?editors=1010

Comment: The "book" is the Vuex documentation that I quoted that was published by gitbook. It was hyperlinked within the quote. Sorry if it wasn't obvious.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I forked the pen as a starting point, and didn't even realise it was vue 1. I've only been using vue 2 for a few weeks now. Have a great day. ( I have another question once I have figured our what you've done :) )